# gSOAP: How to pass info inside soap header

Tags: gsoap, soapheader

I wish to send some information like authentication token inside SOAP header. I am using gSOAP/c/Linux. Please help me how to pass?

My `SOAP_ENV__Header` looks like

```
/* SOAP Header: */
struct SOAP_ENV__Header
{
    struct ns3__Header *ns3__MyHeader;  /* mustUnderstand */
};
```

and `ns3__Header` looks like

```
/* ns3:Header */
struct ns3__Header
{
    char *Value;    /* optional element of type xsd:string */
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering everybody. I figured it out. I did it like:

```
    soap_init(&mysoap);
    mysoap.header = (SOAP_ENV__Header *)soap_malloc(&mysoap, sizeof(SOAP_ENV__Header));
    mysoap.header->ns3__MyHeader = (ns3__Header*)malloc(sizeof(ns3__Header));
    mysoap.header->ns3__MyHeader->Value = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(mysoap.header->ns3__MyHeader->Value, str);
```

But I had to suppress the MustUnderstand attribute like the following:

```
SOAP_FMAC3 int SOAP_FMAC4 soap_out_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap *soap, const char *tag, int id, const struct SOAP_ENV__Header *a, const char *type)
{
      if (soap_element_begin_out(soap, tag, soap_embedded_id(soap, id, a, SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header), type))
            return soap->error;
      //KNG
      //soap->mustUnderstand = 1;
      if (soap_out_PointerTons3__Header(soap, "ns3:MyHeader", -1, &a->ns3__MyHeader, ""))
            return soap->error;
      return soap_element_end_out(soap, tag);
}
```