# Setting soap header with SOAP_ENV__Header in C

Tags: c, gsoap

I've having a difficult time trying to set a SOAP header using gsoap. I've read the FAQ here: http://www.genivia.com/Help/FAQlist.html#g17

This answer wasn't any help: [How to pass header information to the soap header SOAP_ENV__Header, in c++ using gsoap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569324/how-to-pass-header-information-to-the-soap-header-soap-env-header-in-c-using)

It assumes some magical caste has taken place to caste the dummy element in SOAP_ENV__Header to the desired data type.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct SOAP_ENV__Header {
    char *authwsns__token;
    char *authwsns__ip;
};
#define SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header struct SOAP_ENV__Header

#include "authservicesH.h"
#include "AuthServicesBinding.nsmap"

int
main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct soap *soap;
    struct authwsns__GetTokenRequest *request;
    struct authwsns__GetTokenResult *result;

    soap = soap_new();
    soap->header = (struct SOAP_ENV__Header *)soap_malloc(soap, sizeof(struct SOAP_ENV__Header));
    soap->header->authwsns__token = "jc09bdd";
    soap->header->authwsns__ip = "10.10.10.10";

    request = (struct authwsns__GetTokenRequest *)malloc(sizeof(struct authwsns__GetTokenRequest));
    result = (struct authwsns__GetTokenResult *)malloc(sizeof(struct authwsns__GetTokenResult));

    request->tokenBase = id;

    soap_call___authwsns__getToken(soap, "http://", NULL, request, result);

    if (result->tdsns__errorReport) {
        printf("Web services error\n");
        printf("Level:   %s\n",result->tdsns__errorReport->level);
        printf("Message: %s\n",result->tdsns__errorReport->message);
    } else {
        printf("Token is %s\n",result->token);
    }
    soap_end(soap);
    soap_free(soap);
    free(request);
    free(result);
}
```

When I run my program through a debugger and display SOAP_ENV__Header, it still shows it as having a dummy element, so I'm not sure what the correct way to override the default definition is. The explanation in the FAQ is fairly vague about the details of this.

When I hack the Stub.h file with my definition of SOAP_ENV__Header and set values in it, the correct fields show up when I run it through the debugger, but they don't show up in the output XML.

What am I missing here ?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

According to the gsoap documentation, you should define the SOAP Header content in the .h file that you pass to soapcpp2. I recommend to move the following code into the .h file for soapcpp2:

```
struct SOAP_ENV__Header {
    char *authwsns__token;
    char *authwsns__ip;
};
```

Then rerun soapcpp2 on that .h file. Otherwise the serializer implementations in the generated soapC.cpp serializer code are incomplete.

**Edited for clarity**

Answer (score 0):

To define the soap header...

```
#include "soapcalcProxy.h" 
 #include "calc.nsmap" 
 soapStub.h       
 soapH.h          
 soapC.cpp        
 soapClient.cpp
```